# Loading MP3s into the Sound Pool in Android

Tags: android, soundpool

I want to load a couple of MP3s into the sound pool, but I will only be using these MP3s on Activity 3, is it possible to load the MP3s in Activity 1?

Or is this limited to the Activity that loads it uses it?

I can't find the answer in the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load them anytime and use them everywhere. The best thing to re-use the `SoundPool` object would be to extend the `Application` class and declare a private variable in there that is your `SoundPool`. Something like:

```
class MyApp extends Application {
    private static MyApp singleton;

    private static SoundPool mSoundPool;

    public onCreate() {
         super.onCreate();
         singleton = this;
         mSoundPool = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0); Just an example
    }

    public static MyApp getInstance() {
         return singleton;
    }

    public SoundPool getSoundPool() {
         return mSoundPool;
    }
}
```

Now, anywhere on you code you can run:

```
MyApp.getInstance().getSoundPool();
```

and you'll have access to your global SoundPool object.

PS: don't forget to update the Manifest if you extend the Application Class.

Comment: Dont know what you mean by update the manifest if I extend the application class but the rest was good and I think I can google the rest, thanks!!

Comment: He means that you should add the "android:name" property to the application tag in the manifest and put "MyApp" as the value. I'm just posting this comment in case other stackoverflower needs this info :)