# Two onCreate() methods in Android?

Tags: inner-classes, soundpool, android

I am working off another example (found here [Loading MP3s into the Sound Pool in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7061594/loading-mp3s-into-the-sound-pool-in-android)). but for some reason I am ending up with two `onCreate()` methods and if I delete one I am getting errors.

I am trying to load the MP3s into the Soundpool once and then call them in other activities.

My code:

```
class MyApp extends Application {
    private static MyApp singleton;

    private static SoundPool mSoundPool;

    public onCreate() { // ##### Deleting this gives me errors ###, not deleting it gives me 1 error.
         super.onCreate();
         singleton = this;
         mSoundPool = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);// Just an example
    }

    public static MyApp getInstance() {
         return singleton;
    }

    public SoundPool getSoundPool() {
         return mSoundPool;
    }
}


public class TestAndroidGlobalsActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Comment: So you have 1 `onCreate` in application class and another 1 in `Activity`, it's ok. The question is why do you stick `Application` and `Activity` in 1 file.

Comment: I thought thats how it's done here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7061594/loading-mp3s-into-the-sound-pool-in-android If I put it in a seperate file how do I call it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code only has one `onCreate` method per class. They serve different purposes and are called when each of those classes is created by the OS.

Your `MyApp.onCreate` is called when the application is created and sets up application-wide state inside your `MyApp` class.

Your `TestAndroidGlobalsActivity.onCreate` is called when the Activity is created and sets the state for that specific activity an initializes its UI.

Comment: The first onCreate telling me "REturn type for the method missing", what do I do there? (I'm a noob)

Answer (score 1):

you must not confuse Application.onCreate, called when your application is created, and Activity.onCreate, called every time your activity is called (which may happen several times during one application execution)

Also, you should have the @Override annotation above each overriden method.