# Android, How to get this to work?

Tags: android

First of all please note that I am a noob.

What I am trying to do:
Call the code in the other class from the activity 
Once that works I want to start a new activity and call the code from there (please tell me how thats done as well)

I am working off this example:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7061594/loading-mp3s-into-the-sound-pool-in-android

Right now when I click the button it force quits :(

My code:

```
class MyApp extends Application {
    private static MyApp singleton;

    private static SoundPool mSoundPool;
    private HashMap<Integer, Integer> soundPoolMap;

    public static final int A1 = 1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() { // This onCreate is for this class
         super.onCreate();
         singleton = this;
         mSoundPool = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);// Just an example
         soundPoolMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

         soundPoolMap.put(A1,   mSoundPool.load(MyApp.this, R.raw.a,    1));   
    }

    public void playSound(int sound) {
        AudioManager mgr = (AudioManager)MyApp.this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        float streamVolumeCurrent = mgr.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        float streamVolumeMax = mgr.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);    
        float volume = streamVolumeCurrent / streamVolumeMax;

        mSoundPool.play(soundPoolMap.get(sound), volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);     
    }

    public static MyApp getInstance() {
         return singleton;
    }

    public SoundPool getSoundPool() {
         return mSoundPool;
    }
}


public class TestAndroidGlobalsActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    }

        public void next_activity(View v) 
        {
        //MyApp.getInstance().getSoundPool().playSound(1);
MyApp.getInstance().playSound(1);

        }
}
```

My manifest file if you need it:
http://pastebin.com/YHjgGPyd

Thanks!
Ryan

Comment: Add a stacktrace please.

Comment: Whats a stacktrace? And where / how do I add it?

Comment: stacktrace == the entire output of the exception which caused the force close.  Look in the LogCat window in Eclipse.

Comment: LogCat is blank... do I need ot do something to set it up?

Comment: Switch to DDMS Perspective and click on the emulator or device you are testing on.

Comment: Got it, here is what I see as it force closes: http://pastebin.com/MLtdnWxB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your error comes from the fact that you have two application-tags in your manifest. This results in that your second application is never instanciated, so when you try to use it, you get a NullPointerException.

Remove the second one and change your first one to this:

```
<application android:name=".MyApp" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
```

While this example might be good practice to work with, you really should not use the Application-class like this. Let me quote Android Developers:

*"There is normally no need to subclass Application. In most situation, static singletons can provide the same functionality in a more modular way. If your singleton needs a global context (for example to register broadcast receivers), the function to retrieve it can be given a Context which internally uses Context.getApplicationContext() when first constructing the singleton."

http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/app/Application.html

Just google on how to make a nice singleton, and give it an application context in the constructor :)

EDIT:

Here is the same class as a singleton. Best that you use this instead of continuing to use the Application-class.

```
public class MySingleton  {

    private MySingleton instance;

    private static SoundPool mSoundPool;
    private HashMap<Integer, Integer> soundPoolMap;

    public static final int A1 = 1;

    private MySingleton() {
        mSoundPool = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);// Just an example
        soundPoolMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        soundPoolMap.put(A1,   mSoundPool.load(MyApp.this, R.raw.a,    1));
    }

    public synchronized MySingleton getInstance() {
        if(instance == null) {
            instance = new MySingleton();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public void playSound(int sound) {
        AudioManager mgr = (AudioManager)MyApp.this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        float streamVolumeCurrent = mgr.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        float streamVolumeMax = mgr.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);    
        float volume = streamVolumeCurrent / streamVolumeMax;

        mSoundPool.play(soundPoolMap.get(sound), volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);     
    }

    public SoundPool getSoundPool() {
        return mSoundPool;
   }
}
```

Comment: Here's the reason why I did it and used two application tags: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7061594/loading-mp3s-into-the-sound-pool-in-android if you know of a better way to load my mp3s into the soundpool and access them globally i will more than willingly throw out any code that I already have.  Will give your answer a shot now... brb in 3

Comment: Really? I made a pastebin with how your manifest should look now, does this not work? http://pastebin.com/48a0NtXL

Comment: Ok,now it starts with a forceclose... without me doing anything http://pastebin.com/8Ka7kd6D

Comment: Okay, now the correct application is instanciated. But you forgot to declare your class public, so it fails. Declare your class like this: "public class MyApp". But I will also edit into my answer how to make a singleton, so you can practice that also, since it almost always is the preferred way :)

Comment: If I make it public it says "the public class myapp should be declared in its own file". Will try your Singleton example now, but mind telling me how I could call it from another activity class as well? Thanks!

Comment: Oh, well, each class should be in its own java-file :) The singleton however wont need to be public. This is how you get a reference to the singleton: "MySingleton instance = MySingleton.getInstance();" then just go "instance.playSound(1)" or whatever you want to do with it.

Comment: Still not working: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7085584/the-method-loadcontext-int-int-in-the-type-soundpool-is-not-applicable-the-m

Comment: Since those are new errors, could you accept this answer? I'll have a look at the other questions tomorrow if you dont have an answer by then